# Как добавить информацию к существующему компоненту в node_modules Angular 6?

Tags: npm, angular, компоненты

В общем установил компонент [Share Buttons Component](https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-sharebuttons/#/share-button-component) (кнопки шаринга в социальные сети) через NPM в проект и успешно его запустил, однако понадобилось добавить шаринг в OK.ru . Просмотрел исходный код, нашел как добавить, но проблема в том что если я изменю существующий компонент в node_modules, то при старте проекта папка node_modules заново обновляет все пакеты и мой код естественно стирается. Вопрос в том, существует ли способ как то ссылаться на файлы компонента и добавлять в него нужные строки кода?

По сути мне нужно добавить следующую информацию:

В файл `@ngx-share\core\lib\share.models.d.ts` в интерфейс `IShareButtons` добавить переменную `ok?: IShareButton;`

И в файл `@ngx-share\core\fesm2015\ngx-share-core.js` в `const shareButtonsProp` добавить следующий код:

```
ok: {
      type: 'ok',
        text: 'Ok',
        icon: ['fab', 'odnoklassniki'],
        color: '#FF9800',
        share: {
        desktop: 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url=',
          android: 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url=',
          ios: 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url=',
          operators: metaTagsOperators,
          metaTags: {
          url: 'u'
        }
      },
      count: {
        request: 'http',
          url: 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url=',
          operators: FacebookCountOperators
      }
    },
```

Если это как то можно сделать, расскажите пожалуйста как, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Не нужно добавлять "решено" в заголовок вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный компонент поддерживает добавление кастомных кнопок, делается это следующим образом:

```
import { ShareButtons, metaTagsOperators } from "@ngx-share/core";

  constructor(shareButtons : ShareButtons) {
    shareButtons.addButton('ok', {
      type: 'ok',
      text: 'ok',
      icon: ['fab', 'odnoklassniki'],
      color: '#FF9800',
      share: {
        desktop: 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?',
        android: 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?',
        ios: 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?',
        operators: metaTagsOperators,
        metaTags: {
          url :  'url' ,
          title :  'title' ,
          image :  'imageUrl'
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: если вы решили проблему, пометьте ваш ответ как лучший, чтоб вопрос не висел с тегом без "принятого ответа"

Comment: @overthesanity свой собственный ответ я смогу принять только через 2 дня после ответа. Так что придется ждать.